# The field in this expression has an invalid table in this context

Tags: java, jpa

i'm trying to do following query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Grade.findGradeByClassGroup", 
            query= "SELECT gr From Grades gr join DeterminateTable d on gr.DeterminateTableId = d.DeterminateTableId join SchoolYears sy on gr.GradeId = sy.GradeId join ClassGroups cg on cg.schoolYear = sy.YearInt where cg.groupId = :classGroup")
```

And I get this exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6069] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20141202-3914740): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The field [Grades.GradeId] in this expression has an invalid table in this context.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Grade.findGradeByClassGroup" referenceClass=Grade jpql="SELECT gr From Grades gr join DeterminateTable d on gr.DeterminateTableId = d.DeterminateTableId join SchoolYears sy on gr.GradeId = sy.GradeId join ClassGroups cg on cg.schoolYear = sy.YearInt where cg.groupId = :classGroup")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidTableForFieldInExpression(QueryException.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.validateNode(FieldExpression.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression.normalize(Expression.java:3291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.normalize(DataExpression.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.normalize(FieldExpression.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionBuilder.normalize(ExpressionBuilder.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.normalize(DataExpression.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.normalize(FieldExpression.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionBuilder.normalize(ExpressionBuilder.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.normalize(DataExpression.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.QueryKeyExpression.normalize(QueryKeyExpression.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.QueryKeyExpression.normalize(QueryKeyExpression.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildNormalSelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1722)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReadAllQuery.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:342)
    ... 65 more
```

I can't figure out whats wrong, tried to google but couldn't get any answers...

What could be causing this?

Comment: What are your entities? Why don't you have associations between your entities. Why don't half of the fields in your query respect the Java naming conventions?

Comment: yeah i just realized the associations, its working now, for that convention matter, blame my group where I'm developing with ;)